# How to fix the while loop in this program?

Tags: python

Write a python program that will take 3 lists:

Name    **Wage**    *Hours*
Juan    **7.50**    *35*
Rae     **11.00**   *41*
Ivanna  **18.25**   *26*
Lilly   **9.25**    *35*
Robert  **11.10**   *45*

and use this logic:

An employee gets overtime when they have worked more than 40 hours

Overtime pay is calculated using this formula:

Gross Pay = (35*Wage) + ((Hours-35)*Wage*1.5)

Regular pay is calculated using this formula:

Gross Pay = (Hours*Wage)

Use a loop to process these lists.

Print each employee, their wages, Hours and gross pay.

I'm running this program and I have the for loop. The input works fine, but the while loop that its supposed to have the same output is not giving me any output at all. Here's my code.

```
`Name = ["Juan","Rae","Ivanna", "Lilly", "Robert"]
Hours = [35,41,26,35,45]
Wage = [7.5,11,18.25,9.25,11.1]
print ("Name\tWage\tHours\tGP")
for X in range(5):
   GP = 0
   if(Hours[X] > 40):
       GP = (35*Wage[X]) + ((Hours[X]-35)*Wage[X]*1.5)
   else:
       GP = Hours[X] * Wage[X]
   print (Name[X],"\t", Wage[X],"\t", Hours[X],"\t", GP)

Name = ["Juan","Rae","Ivanna", "Lilly", "Robert"]
Hours = [35,41,26,35,45]
Wage = [7.5,11,18.25,9.25,11.1]
print ("Name\tWage\tHours\tGP") 
counter = 5
Y = 0
while (Y):
    if (Hours[Y] > 40):
        GP = (35*Wage[Y]) + ((Hours[Y]-35)*Wage[Y]*1.5)
    else:
        GP = Hours[Y] * Wage[Y]
print (Name[Y],"\t", Wage[Y],"\t", Hours[Y],"\t", GP)`
```

my output is going as

```
Name    Wage    Hours   GP
Juan     7.5     35      262.5
Rae      11      41      484.0
Ivanna   18.25   26      474.5
Lilly    9.25    35      323.75
Robert   11.1    45      555.0
Name    Wage    Hours   GP
Juan     7.5     35      555.0
```

I don't know where the error is in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line needs to be indented. So instead of

```
while (Y):
    if (Hours[Y] > 40):
        GP = (35*Wage[Y]) + ((Hours[Y]-35)*Wage[Y]*1.5)
    else:
        GP = Hours[Y] * Wage[Y]
print (Name[Y],"\t", Wage[Y],"\t", Hours[Y],"\t", GP)
```

it needs to be

```
while (Y):
    if (Hours[Y] > 40):
        GP = (35*Wage[Y]) + ((Hours[Y]-35)*Wage[Y]*1.5)
    else:
        GP = Hours[Y] * Wage[Y]
    print (Name[Y],"\t", Wage[Y],"\t", Hours[Y],"\t", GP)
```

because right now the `print` is outside of the while loop, so it is only printing with the value `Y=0`.

Comment: You missed that the condition needs to be `Y < len(Name)` and there needs to be an increment of `Y` at the end of the loop body `Y += 1`. As it is the loop body will never run as the value of its condition is always falsy.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I tried that before but not correctly together! Now its all good!

Answer (score 0):

Have to follow `python code indented` and need to give proper `while loop condition` with (increment/decrement/boolean). As your code need to increment the value of `Y`.

```
Name = ["Juan","Rae","Ivanna", "Lilly", "Robert"]
Hours = [35,41,26,35,45]
Wage = [7.5,11,18.25,9.25,11.1]
print ("Name\tWage\tHours\tGP")
for X in range(5):
    GP = 0
    if(Hours[X] > 40):
        GP = (35*Wage[X]) + ((Hours[X]-35)*Wage[X]*1.5)
    else:
        GP = Hours[X] * Wage[X]
    print (Name[X],"\t", Wage[X],"\t", Hours[X],"\t", GP)

Name = ["Juan","Rae","Ivanna", "Lilly", "Robert"]
Hours = [35,41,26,35,45]
Wage = [7.5,11,18.25,9.25,11.1]
print ("Name\tWage\tHours\tGP") 
counter = 5
Y = 0
while (Y<counter):
    if (Hours[Y] > 40):
        GP = (35*Wage[Y]) + ((Hours[Y]-35)*Wage[Y]*1.5)
    else:
        GP = Hours[Y] * Wage[Y]
    print (Name[Y],"\t", Wage[Y],"\t", Hours[Y],"\t", GP)
    Y=Y+1
```